# What's the difference between 'commit' and 'revision'

Tags: svn, atlassian-fisheye

What's the difference between a commit and revision? We use SVN, and get metrics from Atlassian Fisheye. There is a report in Fisheye that shows the 'top committers - by revision' and 'top commiters - by commits'.

No-one here can tell me what the difference is.

Many thanks!
Andy

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A commit can contain many file revisions. A file revision is basically a file that is modified as part of a commit so a single commit can have many revisions.

http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/FISHEYE/Glossary#Glossary-Commit

So "Top Committers - By Commit" shows the users who have committed the most changesets/changelists and "Top Committers - By Revision" shows the users who have created the most file versions as part of their commits.

http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/FISHEYE/FishEye+Charts?focusedCommentId=221448800#comment-221448800

Comment: <red-face>Thanks Interrobang, next time I'll RTFM! :)</red-face>

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control):

> Commit:  A commit (checkin, ci or, more rarely, install, submit or record) is the action of writing or merging the changes made in the working copy back to the repository. The terms 'commit' and 'checkin' can also be used in noun form to describe the new revision that is created as a result of committing.

and

> Revision : (Also version) A version is any change in form. In SVK, a Revision is the state at a point in time of the entire tree in the repository.